# how to export unicode character to csv file in R? Is it possible or impossible?

Tags: r, csv, unicode

1. I have text that contains Unicode.
2. Export this text to CSV.
3. I don't want to see Unicode in CSV files created in R.

This is the Unicode in question.

```
<U+00A0>
```

This unicode will appear blank when exported to an xlsx file.
However, when exporting as csv, it comes out as Unicode. It looks like <U+00A0> in the csv file.

How can solve this problem. and I want to know it is possible.

I tried changing the encoding option of the write.table function.
I tried using the iconv function.
But it was not resolved.

Comment: Is it just this one character that needs replaced? Could you replace it in the data before you write the csv? In this case, a normal space would be a good replacement - `my_df$my_column <- gsub('\u00A0', ' ', my_df$my_column)`

Comment: your problem seems to be the way you input your unicode character. in R it would be `'\U00A0'`, not `<U+00A0>`. try; `write.table('to show unicode do\U00A0this \U00B5', file = paste0(getwd(), '/txt.csv'))`